# NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap deploying on WL 12.2.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic, swagger-ui

I need to deploy a Spring boot web application on WL v12.2.1.

Everything is ok on my local Windows WL instance.

Local java version: 1.8.0_171
External java version: 1.8.0_77 -> wl embedded java version

But when i try to deploy the same application on a external Linux WL this error appears:

```
Administration Console encountered the following error:
```

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map;
>               at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:237)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:232)
>               at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:82)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:753)
>               at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:263)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:53)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:601)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:343)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:895)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1422)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:454)
>               at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
>               at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>               at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>               at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>               at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:643)
>               at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
>               at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
>               at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
>               at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>               at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
>               at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
>               at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.asMap(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;)Ljava/util/Map;
>               at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingReferenceScanner.scan(ApiListingReferenceScanner.java:59)
>               at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDocumentationScanner.scan(ApiDocumentationScanner.java:67)
>               at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.scanDocumentation(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:101)
>               at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:167)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
>               at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
>               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
>               at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>               at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>               at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
>               at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
>               at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
>               at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1420)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1359)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1340)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1906)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3063)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1830)
>               at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:875)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
>               at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>               at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)

This is my pom:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <netty.version>4.0.27.Final</netty.version>
        <swagger.version>2.8.0</swagger.version>

        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- apache poi XSSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-bom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.28.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Swagger -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>customlibrary.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>modis-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/modis-security-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>projectName</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Why on my local WL this error doesn't appear?
How can i put this missing class on my classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Solved putting:

```
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>com.google.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
```

on weblogic.xml